# How to Refresh previous Drawer Screen calling from 2nd Screen in Drawer navigation in React-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React-Native project I am using one Navigation drawer. In that drawer I declared two screens - **NoteMeHome** and **MakeNote**. Initially the **NoteMeHome** starts as an initial route of Drawer Navigation. From the **NoteMeHome.js** (first screen) class I go to the **MakeNote.js** (Second Screen). In this **MakeNote.js** class I have used one form to fill. After filling the Form when user clikcs submit it will go back to the previos Screen **( NoteMeHome.js)** and as there is an API call in this **NoteMeHome.js** class, it will refresh and show the submitted data.

But whenever I am going from **MakeNote** Screen to **NoteMeHome** Screen, It just changes to back stack but the the **NoteMeHome** Screen is not refreshed as it is showing the old data.

To control the Drawer flow and structure I have created a class named -

**NavigationDrawerStructure.js**

```
class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null ,
  };

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          {/*Donute Button Image */}
         <Icon name='menu'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: NoteMeHome,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },

});

const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Second: {
    screen: MakeNote,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Create Note',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});



const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Screen1: {
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',

      drawerIcon: (
        <Icon name='home' size={24}

        />
      )

    },
  },

  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Create Note',
      drawerIcon: (
        <Icon name='home' size={24}

        />
      )
    },
  },

});

const DrawerNavigatorExample = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: { screen: Drawer, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  ScreenExternal: {
    screen: ScreenExternal,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Screen External' },
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

In the **MakeNote.js**(Second Screen) I use one function submit to a POST request. Here's the code for that-

```
submit() {
    this.setState({isLoading:true})
    let collection = {}
    collection.timestamp = this.state.timestamp,
    collection.status = this.state.status,
    collection.title = this.state.title,
    collection.detail = this.state.detail,
    collection.url = this.state.url,
    collection.mail = this.state.mail,
    collection.phone = this.state.phone,
    collection.category = this.state.category

    console.log('#HELLO:', collection);

    var url = 'my url';

    if(collection.title != '' ) {

            if(this.state.isNetConnected != false) {

              fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(collection),
                headers: new Headers({
                  'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                  'token': 'abcd',
                  'jwt': this.state.getValue

                })
              }).then(response =>
                {
                  this.setState({isLoading:false});
                  if (response.status !== 200) {
                      console.log('Status Code: ' + response.status);
                      return;
                  }

                  response.json().then(data =>{
                      console.log(data);
                      if(data.status == "saved") {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('First'); 
                    }
                  });
              }
                )
              .catch(error=>{
                this.setState({isLoading:false})
                console.error('Error:', error)

              })

            } else{
              this.setState({isLoading:false});
              Alert.alert("Oops!! No Internet Connection Available");
            }

    } 

    else {
      this.setState({isLoading:false})
      Alert.alert('Please fill up the required field');
    }

  }
```

In the submit function you can see the below line initialize the previous screen back-

```
  if(data.status == "saved") {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('First'); 
                    }
```

It shows the **NoteMeHome**(First Screen) back but no data has been refreshed.

So, I need a solution to refresh this NoteMeHome Screen and show the latest data by API call.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback function as parameter when you call navigate .


Inplace of :

`this.props.navigation.navigate('First');`

Add This:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('First', {
      onGoBack: () => this.refresh(),
    });
```

Then add callback function :

```
refresh() {
  this.doSomething();
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Well, I do the API calling part in the componentDidMount() function in the first screen. So should I call the componentDidMount function in the callback function?

Comment: You can try this approach:

import {NavigationEvents} from 'react-navigation';
Add the component to your render:

<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={() => console.log('I am triggered')} />
Now, this onDidFocus event will be triggered every time when the page comes to focus despite coming from goBack() or navigate.you can add code in this onDidFocus method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion , I solved it following the example given in the below link-

[link]https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html